# Solved: Magento 2 move productpage title around div

Tags: magento2, layout, catalog

I want to move the product **page title** around a container div.
I added the following to my `catalog_product_view.xml` file, but that does not add the div with class container.

What am I missing?

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.title">
            <container name="productpage.title" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="page.wrapper" before="main.content"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Solution is:

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">container</argument>
            </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did the mistake, first, you have to create **container then you have to move**.

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="{Referencecontainer}">
            <container name="productpage.title" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container" />
        </referenceContainer>
    <move element="page.main.title" destination="productpage.title" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks! Also tried that, but it still does not add the div around the page title.